# Any way to see the inverted index of a doc in SOLR

Tags: solr

I am wondering if there is a way to look at the inverted index of a doc in SOLR? I checked solr admin tool but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [LukeRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler) within Solr, should enable you to get the index data.

Comment: Thanks this is certainly useful info to know. I just tried but found that it doesn't show inverted index of fields? It seems to list all raw data? But I am not sure whether I am using it correctly. Is there any particular parameter I need to use? I tried fl but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

there is [Luke](https://code.google.com/p/luke/) but lately is is not being upgraded to latest lucene version, someone will recompile it soon probably.